# Kotlin Coroutines - I can not get them to work to execute on a different threads

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have `SimulationService` that holds simple logic to loop until a `stop()` function has been called. When using Spring Boot Rest that works fine - since web requests to a spring application are scoped into threads and therefore can "interrupt" the main thread running in a loop by changing state - in this case a simple boolean flag that stops the while loop.

Now I wanted to test this behavior for a reason:

```kotlin
internal class SimulationServiceTest {
    private val simulateservice = SimulationService()

    @Test
    fun `should update the amount of ticks ran by the simulation`(): Unit = runBlocking {
        assertThat(SimulationContext.ticks).isEqualTo(0)
        launch(start = CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED, context = Dispatchers.IO) {
            simulateservice.start()
        }
        sleep(1000)
        launch(start = CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED, context = Dispatchers.Default) {
            simulateservice.stop()
        }
        assertThat(SimulationContext.ticks).isGreaterThan(0)
    }
}
```

In this case I just want to test if the `SimulationService` does keep track of the ticks or iterations the while loop has been gone through.
However I am not able to mimic the behavior of web requests with `launch` or `async`.
It behaves just like it does when I use it without CoRoutines.

When `start()` is called - the main thread is stuck in a loop. Therefore I need a CoRoutine that launches to actually access that thread.

I read about CoRoutines not being multiple different threads. However I read that for CoRoutines there is at least **one** new thread created - otherwise there wouldn't be a way to become asynchronous.

I though that `Dispatchers` represent the "new threads". So CoRoutine can run on the DEFAULT, MAIN and IO thread. For me that is DEFAULT & IO shouldn't be the same, right?

How is it happening now - that my CoRoutines still seem to be async onto one thread? The test process is running in indefinitely just like it would act on a common thread.

---

Here is an example how it does with with Java `Executors` thread service:

```
internal class SimulationServiceTest {
    private val simulateservice = SimulationService()

  @Test
    fun `should update the amount of ticks ran by the simulation`() {
        assertThat(SimulationContext.ticks).isEqualTo(0)

        val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        executor.submit {
            simulateservice.start()
        }
        sleep(1000)
        simulateservice.stop()

        assertThat(SimulationContext.ticks).isGreaterThan(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if intentional, but you're using `UNDISPATCHED` coroutine start. Did you read [its documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-start/-u-n-d-i-s-p-a-t-c-h-e-d/)? It starts your coroutine in the *current thread* - no matter which dispatcher you use. Also, you haven't shared your `SimulationService` code, but I have a feeling `start()` is not a suspend fun, and you're basically running it entirely in the main thread because of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I read that for CoRoutines there is at least one new thread created - otherwise there wouldn't be a way to become asynchronous.

What makes you think that? It is entirely possible to run asynchronous stuff on a single thread. JavaScript is basically single-threaded (if you forget about NodeJS's IO handling for a moment), and it has a ton of asynchronous primitives and libraries.

In the coroutines world, you can `launch` a coroutine in the same thread as the current one, it will just wait for its turn to run (like in an event loop). The execution of the coroutines will be interlaced, and the points where the (single) thread switches from one coroutine to another are called *suspension points* (roughly, these are points where you call other suspend functions).

> I though that Dispatchers represent the "new threads". So CoRoutine can run on the DEFAULT, MAIN and IO thread.

Dispatchers are an abstraction over how the coroutines are run. They can indeed represent thread pools on which you dispatch your tasks, but there is no 1-to-1 mapping between a dispatcher and threads. `Dispatchers.Default` and `Dispatchers.IO` are each backed by a pool of threads. The `Default` thread pool is sized based on your CPU cores, whereas the `IO` one can grow as necessary (within some reasonable limit).

> For me that is DEFAULT & IO shouldn't be the same, right?

That is actually not entirely true, because some optimizations regarding those built-in dispatchers allow them to share some threads to reduce context switching and avoid wasting resources unnecessarily. You shouldn't rely on the fact that these threads are the same or different. But it doesn't matter much in your case anyway.

> How is it happening now - that my CoRoutines still seem to be async onto one thread? The test process is running in indefinitely just like it would act on a common thread.

In your current test code, you are not actually dispatching on the `Default` and `IO` dispatchers, because you're running them with [CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-start/-u-n-d-i-s-p-a-t-c-h-e-d/). Therefore, you are running your coroutines in the *current thread* until their first suspension point.

My guess is that `start()` is not even a suspend function itself, and there is no suspension there to release the current thread and give control back to the test's body, so the `sleep()` never gets a chance to run. But in order to confirm that we would need to see the code of the service, and more specifically the `start()` method.